# NavigationDrawerItem'sClickevent

Tags: android

I created NavigationView and set 3 items.

As described in below picture :

[image]

Now what I want is, when I click paticular item, it should start an activity.

How to implement that?

Thanks.!!

Comment: is it a list view on which you are setting item

Comment: hey Kushan check answer suits your problem. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I can understand from your question is that you have used NavigationView for navigation drawer and you must have used menu file for your three menu option as displayed in the image you have shared. You need to handle those three cases in switch-case as given below. Change the menu item id according to your code and you are good to go.

```
navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
            //Checking if the item is in checked state or not, if not make it in checked state
            if(menuItem.isChecked())
                menuItem.setChecked(false);
            else
                menuItem.setChecked(true);
            //To close the menu drawer once it is clicked
            drawerLayout.closeDrawers();

            switch (menuItem.getItemId()){
                case R.id.menu_item_appointments:  //R.id.menu_item_appointment - menu item id which you mentioned in the menu file
                    // Code to start activity

                    return true;

                case R.id.menu_item_upload_status:
                    //code to start activity

                    return true;

                default:
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Oops! Something went wrong.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return true;
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: I used menu file also.I want that click start activity

Comment: Great! Have a nice day! If it helped please upvote the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I assumes that you are using listview in your Navigation drawer, which is a better way, now Check below code:

//to listen click events:

```
mDrawerListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            selectItem(position);
        }
    });
```

Here, position is the item no. of the navigation drawer item clicked. You can use a switch case to identify the item clicked and then call to startActivity using

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Your selectItem should be like this:

```
private void selectItem(int position) {
Intent intent;
switch (position) {
    case 0:
            intent = new Intent(currentActivity, NewActivity.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            currentActivity.startActivity(intent);

        break;
    case 1: // and so on.
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {

            switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {

                case R.id.navigation_item_1:
                    menuItem.setChecked(true);
                    Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, Activity1.class)
                    startActivity(intent1);
                    return true;
                case R.id.navigation_item_2:
                    menuItem.setChecked(true);
                    Intent intent2 = new Intent(this, Activity2.class)
                    startActivity(intent2);
                    return true;
                case R.id.navigation_item_3:
                    menuItem.setChecked(true);
                    Intent intent3 = new Intent(this, Activity3.class)
                    startActivity(intent3);
                    return true;
                case R.id.nav_sub_menu_item01:
                    menuItem.setChecked(true);
                    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity1.class)
                    startActivity(intent);
                    return true;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an OnNavigationItemSelected like the below example .

```
 public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
            ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                    this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
            drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
            toggle.syncState();

            NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
            navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

         @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {


                int id = item.getItemId();
                if (id == R.id.nav_home) {
                } else if (id == R.id.nav_project) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, Project.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, Gallery.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                } else if (id == R.id.nav_contact) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, Contact.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                } else if (id == R.id.nav_login) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, Login.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                } else if (id == R.id.nav_favourites) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, Favourite.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

                    }
                }
```

add these two items in your strings.xml

```
<string name="navigation_drawer_open">Open navigation drawer</string>
    <string name="navigation_drawer_close">Close navigation drawer</string>
```

Comment: I didn't clear onNavigationItemSelected is existing one or should I immplement

Comment: can you please post your navigation drawer xml code.